# Do I need to duplicate my triggers to cover the before insert and before update scenarios?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I created some triggers to make some simple validations. I covered the before insert scenario, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_before_insert_login
BEFORE INSERT ON login
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


   IF (CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.password) < 4 OR  CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.password) > 10) THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '42000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'password must be between 4 e 10 characters';
    END IF;
 ......
```

But if the user performs an update I can't prevent it from entering incorrect data. Do I need to create a before update and duplicate my validation code or there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I think you do need a separate trigger for each one in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't put the logic (your validation code) into [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and execute it inside the separate triggers (insert/update).

```
-- pseudo code
create procedure PASSWORD_VALIDATION(_psswd) { /* validation */ };
create trigger table_ub BEFORE UPDATE { CALL PASSWORD_VALIDATION(NEW.password);};
create trigger table_ib BEFORE INSERT { CALL PASSWORD_VALIDATION(NEW.password);};
```

Thus, your validation code is not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_name]
    ON [dbo].[table_name]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
           'your code here'
    END
```

you can use structure like this to call same trigger for insert,update and delete